# Why is this element returning undefined in the form when I attempt to edit it, but displaying correctly in debugger and console.log?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, patch, json-patch

I keep getting thrown this error: "Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at HTMLDocument". This error occurs when dogName,dogBreed and dogSex and set within the 'click' listener. I am able to click the button and render the information, but once I click the text area to edit dogName etc. for the patch request, this error occurs. If I use debugger or console log, however, it returns exactly what I want it to. Not sure what the issue is? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WKC Dog Show</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main flex'>
      <h1 class='padding margin'>Westminster Kennel Club Dog Show</h1>

      <div class="margin flex">
        <h4 class='center'>Edit Existing Dog</h4>
        <form id='dog-form' class="padding margin border-round border-grey">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="dog's name" value="" />
          <input type="text" name="breed" placeholder="dog's breed" value="" />
          <input type="text" name="sex" placeholder="dog's sex" value="" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="margin flex">
        <h4 class='center'>Registered Dogs</h4>
        <table class='margin' border="1" id='table'>
          <thead class='blue'>
            <tr class='padding'>
              <th class='padding center'>Name</th>
              <th class='padding center'>Breed</th>
              <th class='padding center'>Sex</th>
              <th class='padding center'>Edit Dog</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const dogsUrl = `http://localhost:3000/dogs`
    const table = document.querySelector('#table-body')


function getDogs(){
    fetch(dogsUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(renderDogs)
} 


  const renderDogs = dogs => {      
    table.innerHTML = ''
        dogs.forEach(dog=> {
        const tableRow = document.createElement('tr')
        tableRow.innerHTML = `<td>${dog.name}</td>
        <td>${dog.breed}</td>
        <td>${dog.sex}</td>
        <td><button type="click">Edit this dog!</button></td>`
        tableRow.dataset.id = dog.id
    table.append(tableRow)
})}

document.addEventListener("click",function(e){

    const dogForm = document.getElementById('dog-form')

    const tableRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement

    const dogInfo = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")

    const dogName=dogInfo[0].textContent
    const dogBreed=dogInfo[1].textContent
    const dogSex=dogInfo[2].textContent

    dogForm.name.value = dogName
    dogForm.breed.value = dogBreed
    dogForm.sex.value = dogSex
    dogForm.dataset.id = tableRow.dataset.id

})

document.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()


    const dogForm = e.target
    const id = dogForm.dataset.id
    const name = dogForm.name.value
    const breed = dogForm.breed.value
    const sex = dogForm.sex.value

    fetch(`${dogsUrl}`/`${id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
         },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, breed, sex })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(fetchDogs)
})

getDogs()

})
```

Comment: Your click event listener is hooked up to the document not an element, so `e.target` (and it's parents) will vary depending on where you click. Consider hooking click event to the element you are expecting `e.target` to be on, or use a specific selector for the "tableRow" instead of e.target. See here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: @MattG right got it. thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a click listener on the document and every time you click anything it will execute that code. First thing I would do is limit the event listener to the element you want to listen to – the button. Just add a class to the edit button.

```js
<button type="click" class="edit-dog">Edit this dog!</button>
```

2. Now we have to add the event listener on each of those buttons otherwise it only adds it to the first one. Make an array of buttons and loop over each one to add the event listener.
3. Make a function you call to do all the work when the click occurs `copyDogData`
4. The event listener was being added before the `renderDogs` function had built the html, so place it inside the render dogs function after the `forEach` and your HTML will be built before you try to have event listeners being attached.

Completed Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const dogsUrl = `http://localhost:3000/dogs`;
  const table = document.querySelector("#table-body");

  function getDogs() {
    fetch(dogsUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(renderDogs);
  }

  const renderDogs = (dogs) => {
    table.innerHTML = "";
    dogs.forEach((dog) => {
      const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
      tableRow.innerHTML = `<td>${dog.name}</td>
        <td>${dog.breed}</td>
        <td>${dog.sex}</td>
        <td><button type="click" class="edit-dog">Edit this dog!</button></td>`;
      tableRow.dataset.id = dog.id;
      table.append(tableRow);
    });

    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".edit-dog");

    for (var button of buttons) {
      button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        copyDogData(e.target);
      });
    }
  };

  function copyDogData(target) {
    const dogForm = document.getElementById("dog-form");

    const tableRow = target.parentNode.parentNode;

    const dogInfo = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td");

    const dogName = dogInfo[0].textContent;
    const dogBreed = dogInfo[1].textContent;
    const dogSex = dogInfo[2].textContent;

    dogForm.name.value = dogName;
    dogForm.breed.value = dogBreed;
    dogForm.sex.value = dogSex;
    dogForm.dataset.id = tableRow.dataset.id;
  }

  document.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const dogForm = e.target;
    const id = dogForm.dataset.id;
    const name = dogForm.name.value;
    const breed = dogForm.breed.value;
    const sex = dogForm.sex.value;

    fetch(`${dogsUrl}` / `${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, breed, sex }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(fetchDogs);
  });

  getDogs();
});
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I was trying to do something slightly similar in which I added an Id to the button ('edit'). I added something like the following right before my 
 event listener : const button = document.getElementById('edit') and then changed document.addEventListener to button.addEventListener. This, however, would return a null value for button and thus not allowing me to add the event listener onto it. Can you explain why that is?

Comment: It might be that it worked fine on the first one and then failed for the next buttons. Keep in mind that you should only have one instance of a particular id on a page. IDs must be unique so that the engine can fetch that one element. That's why I used a class and the selector used `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
const tableRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
```

It should be

```
const tableRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
```

Because when you click on `input`, input's parent is `form` and `form` has parent of `div` and this div's parent contains the `table`

```
div.main.flex < div.margin.flex < form < input
```